# jQuery Thumbnail Hover Popup

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I am creating JQuery Show Large Image Preview When Hover On Image In Asp.Net.

please take a look on the following screenshot

[image]

I am using the following Code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Show Image Preview when hover on Link using jQuery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
ShowImagePreview();
});
// Configuration of the x and y offsets
function ShowImagePreview() {
xOffset = -20;
yOffset = 40;

$("a.preview").hover(function(e) {
this.t = this.title;
this.title = "";
var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
$("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='" + this.href + "' alt='Image preview' />" + c + "</p>");
$("#preview")
.css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
.css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
.fadeIn("slow");
},

function() {
this.title = this.t;
$("#preview").remove();
});

$("a.preview").mousemove(function(e) {
$("#preview")
.css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
.css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
});
};

</script>
<style type="text/css">
#preview{
position:absolute;
border:3px solid #ccc;
background:#333;
padding:5px;
display:none;
color:#fff;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(103, 115, 130, 1);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:DataList ID="dtlist" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" CellPadding="5">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" class="preview" ToolTip='<%#Bind("Name") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Name", "~/Images/{0}") %>' runat="server">
<asp:Image Width="100" ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Name", "~/Images/{0}") %>' runat="server" />
</asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle BorderColor="Brown" BorderStyle="dotted" BorderWidth="3px" HorizontalAlign="Center"
VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
</asp:DataList>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Its working fine but when I used to hover any image the hover Image is going outside the page border.

Please help for its not going outside.It will manage something like [This](http://www.gettyimages.in/photos/man?family=creative&phrase=man&sort=best&excludenudity=true).

Comment: place the HTML or better make https://jsfiddle.net/ this makes easy access to answer it. In jQuery you can  get the mousemove x,y position and check whether its greater then your page border x,y values, If its greater then set your preview element left according (minus some value)

Comment: I think you also need to handle `mousemove` also in the document as mentioned in **[this link](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/05/07/faq-show-large-image-on-mouseover-using-javascript.aspx)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I'dint understood :/

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with problem as @Satindersingh mentioned in his comments so that we can actually see what's happening.. Also please mention what is the image size you are using?

Comment: actually  I don't know how to create `asp.net` fiddle because values are coming from database and the size of `thumb` image is `170 x 170` and mousehover is `340 x 340 `. Both Horizontal and vertical images are included on this. @GuruprasadRao

Comment: I just follow the code of http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/09/show-large-image-preview-when-hover-on.html this link @GuruprasadRao

Comment: Alright @Gitz.. I will give a try.. can you somehow give db details atleast so that I can create one copy here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88657/discussion-between-gitz-and-guruprasad-rao).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try using following function to calculate your preview's x-y locations:

Updated HTML with helper functions:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Show Image Preview when hover on Link using jQuery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
ShowImagePreview();
});
// Configuration of the x and y offsets
function ShowImagePreview() {
xOffset = -20;
yOffset = 40;

$("a.preview").hover(function(e) {
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";
        var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
        $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='" + this.href + "' alt='Image preview' />" + c + "</p>");

        var left = getLeft(e,$(this));
        var top = getTop(e,$(this));

        $("#preview")
        .css("top", (top) + "px")
        .css("left", (left) + "px")
        .fadeIn("slow");
    },
    function() {
        this.title = this.t;
        $("#preview").remove();
});

$("a.preview").mousemove(function(e) {

    var left = getLeft(e,$(this));
    var top = getTop(e,$(this));

    $("#preview")
    .css("top", (top) + "px")
    .css("left", (left) + "px");
    });

};

function getLeft(e,obj){
    var left = e.pageX + yOffset;
    var prevWidth = $("#preview").width();
    if((left+prevWidth +50) > $(document).width())
    {
        left = $(obj).offset().left - yOffset - prevWidth;
    }
    return left;
}

function getTop(e,obj){
    var top = e.pageY - xOffset;
    var prevHeigth = $("#preview").height();
    if((top+prevHeigth +50) > $(document).height())
    {
        top = $(obj).offset().top - xOffset - prevHeigth;
    }
    return top;
}

</script>
<style type="text/css">
#preview{
position:absolute;
border:3px solid #ccc;
background:#333;
padding:5px;
display:none;
color:#fff;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgba(103, 115, 130, 1);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:DataList ID="dtlist" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" CellPadding="5">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" class="preview" ToolTip='<%#Bind("Name") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Name", "~/Images/{0}") %>' runat="server">
<asp:Image Width="100" ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Name", "~/Images/{0}") %>' runat="server" />
</asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle BorderColor="Brown" BorderStyle="dotted" BorderWidth="3px" HorizontalAlign="Center"
VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
</asp:DataList>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not getting any result :(

Comment: Moushover image is not displaying after using this

Comment: OK..Give me a min...Will modify your entire HTML and will post into answer

Comment: Hello Gitz, any success with this new HTML?

Comment: Glad to know that..Thanks!